# Why ScopeSecurity object is empty when used in path operation function in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

Here is a simple code to reproduce:

```py
from typing import Annotated, Any

from fastapi import FastAPI, Security
from fastapi.security import SecurityScopes

app = FastAPI()

def dependency_one(scope: SecurityScopes):
    print("dependency function is running.")
    print(f"scope in dependency_one is {scope.scopes}.")

@app.get("/")
def index(
    scope: SecurityScopes,
    obj: Annotated[Any, Security(dependency_one, scopes=["items"])],
):
    print(f"scope in path operation function is {scope.scopes}.")
    return "Hello test"
```

After requesting the `"/"` path, here is the output:

```
INFO:     Started server process [18490]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
dependency function is running.
scope in dependency_one is ['items'].
scope in path operation function is [].
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64055 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

FastAPI correctly collects the scope defined in dependant (`index`) and injects it in to the dependency `dependency_one`. But when I want to use it inside the path operation function, it doesn't inject it and it's empty.

Is that how it is supposed to work? Does that mean I must check and verify the scopes only inside the dependencies' chain and not in the path operation function directly?

The [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/#more-details-about-securityscopes) says:

> It will always have the security scopes **declared in the current
> Security dependencies** and all the dependants for that specific path
> operation and that specific dependency tree.

Comment: Shouldn't your dependency function _return_ the created scope? Right now you're creating two different `SecurityScopes`-objects, one with `scopes` through the constructor to `dependency_one`, and one separate, empty object (which is one you're printing out in your controller). `scope: Annotated[SecurityScope, Security(dependency_one, scopes=["items"])]` and then `return scope` inside `dependency_one` might be what you're looking for? - the `scope` you're reading isn't declared in any current Security dependencies, it's just an empty object by itself.

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm afraid it's not the case. scopes don't need to get returned from dependencies. It's all handled behind the scene magically. I kept the example simple but if I have a chain of dependencies and use `Security` object with a `scheme` in different places, FastAPI will collect the schemes and I have access to them anywhere I use `SecurityScopes` object. The exception is in path operation function... I don't know why.

Comment: Good point, and you're correct - the return value should probably be the current user/etc. in most cases. However, the `SecurityScopes` object you're reading _isn't defined as part of a dependency_. You haven't added the `Security` dependency resolver as part of it, so it isn't being evaluated as a dependency, so I'd guess it isn't part of the "declared in the current Security dependencies" as documented. How would having a dependency that just returns the security dependency work?